# How to use percent on Raphael js Paper.path?

Tags: svg, raphael

Using Rephael js we can do something like:

```
paper.circle('20%', '20%', 30);
```

My question is: how can I do something like (note the use of %):

```
paper.path('M 20% 20% L 100 150');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
var twentyPercent = $('#paper_div').width() * 20/100;//20%
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("paper_div"), paperWidth, paperHeigth);
paper.path("M" + twentyPercent + " " + twentyPercent + "L 100 150");
```

I had to calculate the percentage manually.